# Problem reloading image source in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a camera system ftping image files to a web server every few seconds. I have a web page that uses javascript to reload the source an image tag.

Periodically the web page displays only a portion of the image. I believe this is because the transfer has not completed when the web page request a reload.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            var t = setTimeout("reloadImgs()", 10);

            function reloadImgs() {
                reloadImg("kobmimg");
                reloadImg("eafimg");
                t = setTimeout("reloadImgs()", 5000);               
            }

            function reloadImg(id) {

                var obj = document.getElementById(id);
                var src = obj.src;
                var pos = src.indexOf('?');
                if (pos >= 0) {
                    src = src.substr(0, pos);
                }
                var date = new Date();
                obj.src = src + '?v=' + date.getTime();

                return false;
            }       
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="eaf_camera_image.jpg" id="eafimg" width="350px" />
        <img src="kobm_camera_image.jpg" id="kobmimg" width="350px" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**Any** solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't check any file info using Javascript.  Is there any way you can FTP to a temp file location and have a server side script copy this temp file to the real location upon upload completion?

Comment: The camera can ftp to any folder on the server. I am trying to avoid server side code because I don't want the page to blink on updates. If I chose to use server side code I'd just check to see if the file was open before loading the page/image. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the image has not been fully loaded to the server when you change the source and the browser requires the new image.

You should make the image available to the browser only when it's been fully loaded.

This means the script on your server should upload the image on a separated folder, or perhaps with a different name, then when it's fully loaded (and you could know this by updating a database field for example), you copy the image to the folder where your script can download it.

You should also inform your script if the image is available or not by sending a request first and check what is the response. Otherwise, since your script is adding a different variable every time to avoid cache, you will end up downloading the image even if it's the same image you have now.

```
Camera -> Upload image -> Image fully uploaded? -> Update database entry

Browser request image -> Server check -> Available? -> Download image
```

Comment: The only problem with this is the hardware ftping the image is basically a black box. All I can do is set the ftp address login info and timing parameters.

Comment: That's ok, the important thing is your script in the server must check if the image has been fully loaded or not, before making it available for the browser to download.

Answer (score 2):

Your assessment looks probable to me: the web page is loading an image that's only partially uploaded. You have multiple options:

- configure your FTP server to keep the files in a temp location until upload is finished (not sure if all FTP servers support this)
- if the camera supports some sort of callback on upload complete (few do), use *that* to trigger the copy, show the older image until then
- if none of that is an option, configure your camera to upload the files to a different location than the webserver's document root, and run a script that periodically copies the files to the final location (e.g. from one directory on the webserver to another)

Comment: The company uses IIS ftp server, not sure if that's possible but I'll check.The camera has not options for this. Because of how often I want to update I feel I may run into the same issue with option #3. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could ftp the images to a folder that is not your live folder, then use a cron job to move images into the serving folder.  Your reloadImgs method could do a time check to make sure you're not in the cron window, if it were it could skip that reload cycle and wait again.

Comment: I think I'd run into the same issue, if the page were to update as the 'cron' job was running. Don't you agree.

Comment: Well you could have the cron job create a marker and remove the marker when it's done running, and if reloadImgs() found the marker they could skip that refresh cycle. Create and remove a temp file you could check for, some sort of flag to know the state of the job.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your camera system is ftping images incorrectly, otherwise how large are images and how slow is your connection that you have this issue... Anyway I can suggest a solution, that would help in my opinion.

```
try using jQuery to do this:
$('#eafimg').load(function(){
    setTimeout('reloadImg ("eafimg")', 5000) ;
}
$('#kobmimg').load(function(){
    setTimeout('reloadImg ("kobmimg")', 5000) ;
}
```

Comment: I honestly do not think using jquery would fix this issue.